# SASS: Mixins vs Inheritance

Tags: css, sass, less

If **using inheritance (extends)** and **mixins without arguments** are bad practices, then which one would you choose if you just want to share style properties to your other css selectors?

Comment: https://csswizardry.com/2014/11/when-to-use-extend-when-to-use-a-mixin/

Comment: I assume this question will be closed as answers may be seen as opinion based. The article that @Arkellys linked points out that using mixins without arguments is not necessarily a bad practice so if your are limited to extend or include, include is your better choice. Though this kind of goes beyond your question and it depends on the style rules, another approach is using more classes a la bootstrap which has the benefit that not too many things are tied to a single selector. From a debugging and maintenance perspective, I'd prefer to see some widely shared styles as a separate class.